# How to load values of one table to another automatically in MySQL..?

Tags: mysql

there is a existing table A. suppose  i want to add all or specific(column) values of an existing table A to  table B using foreign key, how do i do it in MySQL?
 and if there  is any new insert or update in table A it should automatically insert into table B also..

Comment: Why do you wish to duplicate values?, why not just use a view? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Answer (score 1):

To automatically update Table B from changes in Table A would require triggers that MySQL supports but phpMyAdmin does not. If instead you're looking to insert rows into Table B from Table A on an ad-hoc basis then that's simple

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA (COL1, COL2, COL3)
SELECT FROM TABLEB (COL1, COL2, COL3) 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA WHERE TABLEA.COL1 = TABLEB.COL1) = 0
```

The above SQL does a simple copy from TableB into TableA. The WHERE clause ensures only records which don't already exist are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use insert/update trigger for that.

Answer (score 0):

Why should you want to do that? 
Why don't you just reference the data in table A using the forign key in table B you mentioned?

Comment: but then, i have insert the same value from table A to table B . its always better if there was a automatic way .

Comment: Yes, however, the question was: Why do you need the same value in both tables, since they are joinable via the foreign key anyway?

Answer (score 0):

`insert into tableb(columns) select columns from tablea`